# How to put string parameters in functions inside f strings?

Tags: python, f-string

I have the following f-string:

```
f"Something{function(parameter)}"
```

I want to hardcode that parameter, which is a string:

```
f"Something{function("foobar")}"
```

It gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '('
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You can use second type of quote character which is `f"Something{function('foobar')}"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because f-strings are recognized by the lexer, not the parser, you cannot nest quotes of the same type in a string. The lexer is just looking for the next `"`, regardless of its context. Use single quotes inside `f"..."` or double quotes inside `f'...'`.

```
f"Something{function('foobar')}"
f'Something{function("foobar")}'
```

Escaping quotes is not an option (for reasons that escape me at the moment), which means arbitrarily nested expressions are not an option. You only have 4 types of quotes to work with:

1. `"..."`
2. `'...'`
3. `"""..."""`
4. `'''...'''`

Comment: *"Escaping quotes is not an option"* - I bet language designers did not want to deal with the awkward escaping madness which could happen inside f-string expressions, and decided to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that python has two types of quotes:

```
f"Something{function('foobar')}"
```

or

```
f'Something{function("foobar")}'
```

What you unfortunately can't do, is escape the inner string's quotes. `f"Something{str.upper(\"foobar\")}"` will result in

```
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
```

This is specifically addressed in [PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#escape-sequences), which defines how f-strings work.

Answer (score 0):

Python allows both "" and '' around strings. Easiest is to use:

```
f"Something{function('foobar')}"
```