# Replace placeholder in string stored in a variable

Tags: python

I have a variable `mystr`, that will contain strings like

```
name = 'John'
mystr = 'src/edu/{name}/obj.txt'
```

I have to replace `{name}` in `mystr` with the actual value which is stored in another variable, i./e. `name`.

However, the catch is that the value of `mystr` is not hardcoded. I have shown here only for demonstration purposes. Actually, it gets assigned from another function, which means the value could be anything. But no matter what the value is, `{name}` needs to be replaced with the actual value.
For e.g. in first iteration -

`mystr = 'src/edu/{name}/obj.txt'`,

in second iteration -

`mystr = 'code/new/{name}/obj2.txt'`, and so on.

So the solution has to be generic that no matter what string gets assigned to `mystr` it should replace the `{name}` placeholder.

```
If mystr = 'src/edu/{name}/obj2.txt'
```

then output :

```
'src/edu/john/obj2.txt'
```

If `mystr = 'src/edu/{name}/obj2.txt'`

then output:

```
'src/edu/john/obj2.txt'
```

I have tried f-strings, but it only works on hard-coded strings.

Comment: not sure I have got your question RIGHT , didi you have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70428172/how-to-put-string-parameters-in-functions-inside-f-strings

Comment: OK I got it : The problem with using f-strings is that variables are instantly replaced by the variable in the current scope, thus it becomes more complex to store the template.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351740/how-can-i-use-f-string-with-a-variable-not-with-a-string-literal How can I use f-string with a variable, not with a string literal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's `format` method for strings, which is what f-strings are shorthand for.

```py
mystr = 'src/edu/{name}/obj.txt'
formatted = mystr.format(name="john") # 'src/edu/john/obj.txt'
```

or, from a variable

```py
myname = "john"
mystr = 'src/edu/{name}/obj.txt'
formatted = mystr.format(name=myname) # 'src/edu/john/obj.txt'
```

You can read more about the `.format` method from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format` or `replace`:

```
out = mystr.format(name="john")
```

or

```
out = mystr.replace("{name}", "john")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .format() method or .replace() methods for string manipulation in Python. Example code:

```
output_string = mystr.format(name="john")
```

or

```
output_string = mystr.replace("{name}", "john")
```

If you want to use variables, then you can just replace the string “john” with the variable. Example code:

```
user_name = "john"

output_string = mystr.format(name=user_name)
output_string = mystr.replace("{name}", user_name)
```

Comment: the name 'john' comes from a variable, say x. How do I use the variable ?

Comment: If variable x is a string, then you can just replace “john” with x. So, the code would be: output_string = mystr.format(name=x)